# Pytest: Update a global variable in test

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, pytest-django

I am new to Python and am using pytest for testing

I am executing the pytest from within the python script. I have a global variable in the script which I modify based on the result in the test. The updated global variable is again used after the tests are executed.

```
import pytest
global test_suite_passed
test_suite_passed = True

def test_toggle():
   global test_suite_passed
   a = True
   b = True
   c = True if a == b else False
   test_suite_passed = c
   assert c

def test_switch():
   global test_suite_passed
   one = True
   two = False
   three = True if one == two else False
   if test_suite_passed:
      test_suite_passed = three
   assert three


if __name__ == '__main__':
   pytest.main()
   if not test_suite_passed:
      raise Exception("Test suite failed")
   print "Test suite passed"
```

I have two questions:

1) The above code snippet prints "Test suite passed", whereas I am expecting an Exception to be raised as the second test case has failed.

2) Basically, I want a handle to the result of the pytest, through which I can get to know the number of test cases passed and failed. This shows up in the test summary. But I am looking for a object which I can use further in the script after the tests are executed

Comment: never use global variables. never use global variables with testing.

Answer (score 1):

pytest is designed to be called from command line, not from inside your test script. Your global variable does not work, because pytest imports your script as module, which has it's own namespace.

To customize the report generation, use the post-process-hook:
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures

Comment: Thank you for the response. Basically I have this pytest running as a subprocess of Java. That's the reason I am invoking the tests from the script itself. The link you have posted is good, but it's kind of complicating things for me. All I need is that the python sub process(pytests) should run all the tests. But the process should exit with an exception if there's atleast one failure in the entire test suite.Else it should make a graceful exit This will help validating the exit code of subprocess from Java side. That's why I've the global variable to know if the testsuite has passed

Comment: The post process plugin is called for very assert in the test case. Could you tell how I can maintain a state here to find out if any of the test cases has failed. I want all the testcases to be executed even if one testcase fails in between. But after all the testcases have finished executing, and if one of the testcases has failed, I want to throw an exception. That's the reason I had the global variable to maintain that state. I can probably read from the 'failures' file to check if a testcase has failed as suggested in the link you mentioned, but that's an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the exit code return when calling **pytest.main()**  The global variable is not necessary

```
import pytest

def test_toggle():
    a = True
    b = True
    c = True if a == b else False
    assert c

def test_switch():
    one = True
    two = False
    three = True if one == two else False
    assert three


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit_code = pytest.main()
    if exit_code == 1:
        raise Exception("Test suite failed")
    print "Test suite passed"
```